# How does one download an XML file through Puppeteer.js?

Tags: node.js, xml, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to download a xml file through puppeteer; however, the program repeatedly crashed in the process. I am including my code attempts below and the error messages.

**ATTEMPT 1**: Clicks on link to .docx file

**ERROR MESSAGE**: "buffer error message: Could not load body for this request. This might happen if the request is a preflight request."

**CODE THAT CAUSES ERROR(line 26)**:

```
let buffer;
page.on("response", async response => {
    if(response.url().endsWith('.docx')){
        try {
            //CAUSE OF ERROR
            buffer = await response.buffer()
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`buffer error message: ${error.message}`)
        }
    }
});
```

**CODE**

> ```
> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
>
> const downloadFile = async () => {
>
>     //create browser session
>     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
>         headless: true,
>         userDataDir: "./BrowserData"
>     });
>
>     //create page
>     const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
>     await page.setRequestInterception(true)
>
>     //allow all requests to go through
>     page.on('request', async request => {
>         request.continue();
>     });
>
>     //test responses for type .docx and save to buffer
>     let buffer;
>     page.on("response", async response => {
>         if(response.url().endsWith('.docx')){
>             try {
>                 //CAUSE OF ERROR
>                 buffer = await response.buffer()
>             } catch (error) {
>                 console.error(`buffer error message: ${error.message}`)
>             }
>         }
>     });        
>
>     //searches for .docx links on google 
>     try {
>         await page.goto("https://www.google.com/search?q=type%3Adocx&sxsrf=ALiCzsYSc2CfabaHQHZdsQMgxFOFv2y0OQ%3A1664557191759&ei=hyA3Y93tLcLY5NoP0oO48A4&ved=0ahUKEwidzf3g_rz6AhVCLFkFHdIBDu4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=type%3Adocx&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6CggAEEcQ1gQQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQpAZYpAZg1AhoAXABeACAATuIATuSAQExmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz");
>     }          
>     catch(e){
>         console.error("error message:", e)
>     }
>
>     //finds .docx link anchor tag
>     const link = await page.$("a[href='https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx']");
>     
>     //clicks on .docx file link
>     await page.evaluate((link) => {
>         link.click();
>     }, link);
> };
>
> downloadFile();
> ```

**ATTEMPT 2**: Directly goes to .docx file link during initialization.

**ERROR MESSAGE**: "Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at [https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx"](https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx%22)

**CODE THAT CAUSES ERROR (line 32)**:

```
//go to the file page  
try {
    //CAUSE OF ERROR
    await page.goto("https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx");     
}          
catch(e){
    console.error("error message:", e)
}
```

**CODE**

> ```
> const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
>
> const downloadFile = async () => {
>     //create browser session
>     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
>         headless: true,
>         userDataDir: "./BrowserData"
>     });
>     
>     //create page
>     const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
>     await page.setRequestInterception(true)
>     
>     //allow all requests to go through
>     page.on('request', async request => {
>         request.continue();
>     });
>     
>     //test responses for type .docx and save to file
>     page.on("response", async response => {
>         if(response.url().endsWith('.docx')){
>             try {
>                 const buffer = await response.buffer()
>             } catch (error) {
>                 console.error(`buffer error message: ${error.message}`);
>             }
>         }
>     })        
>     
>     //go to the file page  
>     try {
>         //CAUSE OF ERROR
>         await page.goto("https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx");     
>     }          
>     catch(e){
>         console.error("error message:", e)
>     } 
> };
>
> downloadFile();
> ```

Puppeteer has no problem downloading images or json, but xml causes problems. Are there any ways to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've got the same issue, but with a .txt attachment